# Importing Data from CoinMarketCap

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, pickle, pandas-datareader

I am following a Youtube tutorial that is importing data from Yahoo for the S&P500 and I am attempting to instead import data from coinmarketcap to track cryptocurrency data.

I am attempting to use Pandas DataReader to get data from coinmarketcap but am getting an error (NotImplementedError: data_source='coinmarketcap' is not implemented).

I am not sure if my syntax is wrong or if I'm missing a module or I am using the incorrect data_source implementation.

Here's the code:

```
import coinmarketcap

import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
import os
import pandas_datareader as web
import pickle
import requests

def save_cmc_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table floating-header'})
    #table1 = soup.find('table', {'class': 'no-wrap text-right'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('a')[0].text
        price = row.findAll('a', {'class': 'price'})[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)
        tickers.append(price)

    with open("cmctickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(tickers, f)

    print(tickers)

    return tickers

    #save_cmc_tickers()

    def get_data_from_cmc(reload_cmc100=False):

    if reload_cmc100:
        tickers = save_cmc_tickers()
    else:
        with open("cmctickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')

    start = dt.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    end = dt.datetime(2017, 12, 31)

    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
            df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'coinmarketcap', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print("Already have {}".format(ticker))

get_data_from_cmc()
```

I was also getting a "EOFError: Ran out of input" error earlier, so I don't know if that has anything to do with it, but that is no longer appearing.

Any information would help greatly. Thanks.

Comment: As the error message tells you, `'coinmarketcap'` isn't an [expected source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/data.py#L306).

Comment: This one scrapes coinmarketcap and it only uses the python requests library: https://github.com/rootVIII/crypto_csv_writer

Comment: They have an API here `https://coinmarketcap.com/api/`, if that does what you want, it would work a lot better. Pick `Basic` for the free version

Answer (score 1):

`pandas_datareader` does not provide support for CoinMarketCap. This is why a `NotImplementedError` has been raised.

Separate note: It may not be necessary to scrape the CoinMarketCap for the data you are seeking, as CoinMarketCap has a developer API ([link](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/)) which could be accessed as follows (after [obtaining an API key](https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/signup/])), though only certain endpoints are covered in the free plan.

```py
# python 3
import requests

url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/historical"

params = {
    "time_start": "2017-01-01",
    "time_end": "2018-01-01",
    "interval": "1d"
}

headers = {
    "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "<YOUR_API_KEY>"   
}

r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
r.json()
```